# slick.js - why is the first slide cloned when using bootstrap row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slick.js

I want to use the slick.js slider and in it some bootstrap row and col stuff. However, when I use

```
 <div class="row">
```

on the first slide, it's content is cloned and showed on the second slide, too.
Does anybody know, how to fix that?

fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7txLhv6f/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put contents in the other slides you get the expected behavious (eg 1, 2, 3). Is this an acceptable solution?

Comment: unfortunately not, since I need <div class="row"> in all the slides and it somehow messes the slides up, see http://jsfiddle.net/xy2n3rxe/

Comment: now it works, I just included the row divs each in another <div>